# .then() Promise stops working and logs undefined but the return object is filled correct (Next 13.5.6)

Tags: next.js, next.js13

We are currently building an application which, among other things, includes user management / container management features. All of these are displayed using basic CRUD operations [Screenshot CRUD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlVdE.png). For each action, such as editing a container, there is a small form displayed on the corresponding button, as shown in this popup [Screenshot Edit Container Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmc20.png).

After form submission, we call our database function to update the container, using the following code as an example:

edit-container-form.js (client component)

```
editContainer(oldContainer, newContainer).then((res) => {
                console.log(res)
                if (!res.error) {
                    editCallback(true, container, returnContainer)
                    router.refresh();
                } else {
                    console.log(res)
                    editCallback(false)
                }
            })
```

Our function edit Container should be returning the new container after updating it in the database like this.

"databaseActions.ts"

```
try {

        const response = await myPrisma.container.update({
            where: {
                id: oldContainer.id
            },
            data: {
                name: newContainer.name,
                group:{
                    connect: { id: newContainer.group.id }
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(response)
        return response;
    } catch (error: any) {
        if (error.code === "P2002") {
            return {
                error: `This control is already taken`,
            };
        } else {
            return {
                error: error.message,
            };
        }
    }
```

The update with Prisma is functioning correctly, and the database is updated accordingly. When I use console.log(response), it logs the updated container to the console, but console.log(res) logs undefined. I'm uncertain when this functionality ceased to work because it was functional in our previous releases. I'm eager to resolve this issue and restore its functionality, but I've run out of ideas.

Tried rebuilding the project, removing node_modules. Error occures in npm run dev and npm run start. Added try/catch around the prisma call, added various console.log() to try and find the error in my code.